# COPY statement inside stored procedure

Tags: sql, postgresql

My issue is that I'm not able to run a COPY statement inside an stored procedure, and I don't know why.

My function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION copy_table(mynumber integer)
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
DECLARE 
    iNumber integer := 0;

BEGIN   
    iNumber := mynumber;

    RAISE NOTICE 'my number: %', iNumber;

    IF(iNumber <> 0) THEN
        COPY (SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE number = iNumber) TO '/tmp/test.csv' WITH CSV;
    END IF;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION copy_table(integer)
  OWNER TO "owner";
```

Now, if I do now:

```
COPY (SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE number = 2) TO '/tmp/test.csv' WITH CSV
```

I just get the desired result, but if I use the function described earlier as:

```
SELECT copy_table(2)
```

I get the error:

```
NOTICE:  my number: 2


ERROR:  there is no parameter $1
LINE 1: COPY (SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE number =  $1 ) TO '/t...
                                                         ^
QUERY:  COPY (SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE number =  $1 ) TO '/tmp/test.csv' WITH CSV
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function "copy_table" line 10 at SQL statement


********** Error **********

ERROR: there is no parameter $1
SQL state: 42P02
Context: PL/pgSQL function "copy_table" line 10 at SQL statement
```

Any help will be much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: looking at http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/b42b73150909161302y3564dc4am28701b4898366f6@mail.gmail.com it seems this is a bug. It suggests using dynamic sql as a workaround.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a bug in Postgres ([reference](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/b42b73150909161302y3564dc4am28701b4898366f6@mail.gmail.com)). It suggest using dynamic SQL as a workaround. However you can't use bind variables. So, something like this (untested as I'm pretty sure SQLFiddle isn't going to let me create files).

```
Create or replace function copy_table(mynumber integer) returns void as $$
Declare
    sql varchar;
Begin
    If mynumber <> 0 Then
        sql = 'copy (select * from mytable where number = ' 
            || mynumber::varchar || ') to ''/tmp/test.csv'' with CSV;';
        execute sql;
    End if;
End;
$$ Language plpgsql;
```

Comment: this approach worked fine, it's just a shame that it's necessary but oh well, thank you!